# Draw a map based on values from the source point

Tags: python, python-3.x, geometry, pygame

I want to make a map. So I have values in an array and I want to use those values to make a map. So the values are from 1 to 250 and there are 120 of them (one for 3 degrees). So how do I calculate where should I put my points based on the values in the right order (from 0 to 360 degrees)?

Here is my code so far:

```
import pygame

white = (255, 255, 255)
black = (0, 0, 0)
import sys
pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_caption("Drawing is fun!")
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((500, 500))
screen.fill(white)
pygame.draw.circle(screen, black, (250, 250), 250, 1)
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit();
            sys.exit();
    pygame.display.update()
    clock.tick(60)
```

I don't have the array yet but I will have it in the near future. Let's say that the array is named `values`.

For those who didn't understand my question:
- I have a 500 x 500 pygame canvas.
- I have 120 values which represent 3 degrees each. We got them by spinning an ultra sonic sensor around and reading the values.
- I want to create an image on the canvas that reads those values and puts points in the image and then it connects them forming lines.
- It will be like a map generated by an ultrasonic sensor.

Comment: Could you reformulate the question and explain better? There is nothing clear...

Comment: Here you go dude I fixed it.

Comment: And every value gives a distance to the object in this sector?

Comment: Yes every value is actually from 30 - 2550mm and it gives the distance from the source point to the object directly in front of it(in the real world) I want to map these values onto an image and connect them with lines

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So full size of your field is `2w=500`, and half-size is `w=250`

Center of field has coordinates `(cx, cy)` = `(w, w)`

Distance are already normalized in you case (max value 250 = w)

If your objects are point in the center angle of the sector, then screen coordinates of object at i-th index are

```
central_angle = (1.5 + i * 3) * Pi / 180  //in radians
x = cx + Round(values[i] * Cos(central_angle))   //round float value to get integer coordinate
y = cy + Round(values[i] * Sin(central_angle))
```

Comment: Hey dude your code doesn't work it says unresolved refrence Cos, Sin, Pi and Round. Are these used in python 2.7?

Comment: i found all of them except cy and cx

Comment: dude can you rewrite the code so i can use it from scratch

Comment: it gives me an index error and ur math doesn't check out. when i manually put in numbers instead of an array and it didn't give me possible coordinates. when i put it through a loop. it says index out of range error on your behalf

Comment: Emm.. My pseudocode gives just an idea how to calculate points. Search for mistakes in your implementation using debug.